# Spring Stomp over Websocket: Message/Buffer/Cache/Stream limits

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

Could not understand the different parameters in the stomp over websocket config I am using for developing a chat application that involves images/vidoes:

*I notice that the SockJs in webpage, sends message with a frame size of 16K. I also tested that the message size limit is what determines the max size of message that I can transfer.*

Could you please let me know what is:

1. stream bytes limit
2. send buffer size limit
3. http message cache size
4. What is partial messages and how to use them and are they useful here?
5. Also I plan on setting the max size of image/video to 2GB and expects about 100 simultaneous users when I release.

Could you please let us know what sizes should I keep and why? What are the defaults? And how each of them would affect the performance of my chat application?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/stomp").withSockJS()
            .setStreamBytesLimit(15 * 1024)
            .setHttpMessageCacheSize(15 * 1024);
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/", "/exchange/");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
    registration.setSendTimeLimit(15 * 1000)
            .setSendBufferSizeLimit(1 * 1024)
            // max message size 2GB (2048 bytes) : default is 64KB
            .setMessageSizeLimit(2 * 1024 * 1024);
}
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering question with my findings and implementation:

In the below configuration:

```
@Override
public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
    registration.setSendTimeLimit(60 * 1000)
            .setSendBufferSizeLimit(200 * 1024 * 1024)
            .setMessageSizeLimit(200 * 1024 * 1024);
}
```

1. stream bytes limit : info from source

   ```
   /**
    * Streaming transports save responses on the client side and don't free
    * memory used by delivered messages. Such transports need to recycle the
    * connection once in a while. This property sets a minimum number of bytes
    * that can be send over a single HTTP streaming request before it will be
    * closed. After that client will open a new request. Setting this value to
    * one effectively disables streaming and will make streaming transports to
    * behave like polling transports.
    * <p>The default value is 128K (i.e. 128 * 1024).
    */
   public SockJsServiceRegistration setStreamBytesLimit(int streamBytesLimit) {
       this.streamBytesLimit = streamBytesLimit;
       return this;
   }
   ```
2. send buffer size limit
   default is 512KB. If message sending is slow, subsequent messages are buffered until either the sendTimeLimit or the sendBufferSizeLimit are reached.
3. http message cache size: info from source

   ```
   /**
    * The number of server-to-client messages that a session can cache while waiting for
    * the next HTTP polling request from the client. All HTTP transports use this
    * property since even streaming transports recycle HTTP requests periodically.
    * <p>The amount of time between HTTP requests should be relatively brief and will not
    * exceed the allows disconnect delay (see
    * {@link #setDisconnectDelay(long)}), 5 seconds by default.
    * <p>The default size is 100.
    */
   public SockJsServiceRegistration setHttpMessageCacheSize(int httpMessageCacheSize) {
       this.httpMessageCacheSize = httpMessageCacheSize;
       return this;
   }
   ```
4. What is partial messages and how to use them and are they useful here?
   **Still not sure how to stream large files over websocket and use partial messaging (decided to use HTTP for that instead)**
5. Also I plan on setting the max size of image/video to 2GB and expects about 100 simultaneous users when I release.
   => set by messageSizeLimit
   and used HTTP to do file uploads/ streaming downloads. Also set up the server limits using apache file-upload config:

   ```
   //set up the server limits using apache file-upload config
   @Bean
   public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
       CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
       resolver.setMaxUploadSize(2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024); // 2 GB limit set for file upload
       resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
       return resolver;
       }
   ```

Comment: How to configure SockJsServiceRegistration?(Can you provide code how to get it and how to configure? just new SockJsServiceRegistration?)